# I need to copy one folder of files from my iPhone 11 Pro Max and I can't

Tags: iphone, icloud, finder, backup

I need to copy one folder of files from my iPhone 11 Pro Max and I can't.

When I try to select 1677 photos and share them to Google Drive, the dialog box disappears and does nothing when I click upload button.

When I try to first migrate those 1677 photos from my iPhone 11 Pro Max to Mac Book Pro, I tried several options which also do not work.

1. Tried to share through AirDrop to Mac Book Pro, but for unknown reason the laptop doesn't appear as available recipient (I have Bluetooth and WIFI turned on on both devices and I can share file by AirDrop from Mac Book Pro to iPhone but not vice versa. AirDrop discoverability is set to Everyone on both devices).
2. Tried to connect by a USB cable, now I can't select a particular folder on Mac. I am limited on options all-or-nothing, it allows me to bring either all the files or nothing, and doesn't allow me to select a particular folder.
3. Tried to connect by a USB cable to a PC laptop. I am able to see the folders, but it is messed up and the folder structure visible in File Explorer doesn't correspond the folder structure on iPhone, so I can't select the folder I need, since I can't find this folder and the displayed folders like 202109__ do not correspond to the folders shown in My Iphone / Folder.
4. I tried to delete all photos from iCloud backup and then put the desired folder in iCloud backup. It failed to store all the desired files from the specific folder. Only 1304 photos were moved to iCloud because of the limitation of 5 GB.

Is there a way to backup selected files into desired cloud?

Comment: Are these files on iCloud?  If so, have you tried downloading them from iCloud.com?

Comment: I can't put them on iCloud due to iCloud limitatino

Comment: Have you tried restarting both the Mac and the iPhone? AirDrop sometimes has its quirks but usually when it works it is great.

Comment: Yes, I have restarted both devices

Answer (score 2):

I have dozens of folders with that many files working very well with iCloud. If you can’t get the google drive service to work reliably, paying for one month of iCloud would get the job done without needing a computer.

We also use Finder to sync files, many more than that so I don’t see any issues inherent with the OS or design since this is small size of files to sync for the work population I support. We don’t use google but we do have people using OneDrive instead of iCloud. My iCloud experience is personal use but I’ve got 200 GB of files currently in iCloud.

You didn’t mention specifically where the photos are.  If it’s in photos app you might want to sync that to iCloud or the Mac and export then to google drive if you can’t just save those to files app first and then save to google drive.

Steps for that:

1. Add the photos to album if needed
2. Select photos in the photos app
3. Tap the share icon (square with arrow)
4. Tap save to files
5. Choose where on file system you want the shared / exported files to live

https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/share-photos-and-videos-iphf28f17237/ios

Comment: I have described that this didn't work for me. I have tried to make an album from the photos and store it both in My Iphone and iCloud, iCloud wasn't able to store the files. Where they are in My iPhone folder, I can't get this folder copied to laptop or google cloud

Comment: I understand you’re struggling but wanted to provide options and context in case you didn’t know how to export photos. Can you export 5 and sync them? @Patlatus